# Value of set of input tags in a JS array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a set of input tags

```
<input name= "keys[]" type="text">
<input name= "keys[]" type="text">
<input name= "keys[]" type="text">
<input name= "keys[]" type="text">
<input name= "keys[]" type="text">
```

Is it possible to get all the input of type text values in an array using the name keys[]

I tried this

```
$('input[name="keys[]"]').val()
```

But I got the value of the first input tag only.

I wanted to get a array of the values of these input tags. Is it possible without going thru an iteration?

Thanks

Comment: There is no value attribute?

Comment: from the [manual](https://api.jquery.com/val/): `Get the current value of the **first element** in the set of matched elements.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `serializeArray()` it will return an array of objects with name and value.

```
$('input[name="keys[]"]').serializeArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
$('input[name="keys[]"]').map(function(key, input) { return input.value; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
var array= new Array();
$('input[name="keys[]"]').each(function(index){
 array[index] = $(this).val();
});
```

Hope I help!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Gh6Z9/4/

```
var values = new Array();
$.each( $('input[name="keys[]"]'), function() {
 values.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(values);
```